# Ubuntu in VMware 11 and Cooler Master LED keyboard

Tags: keyboard, vmware, backlight

I just want to try Ubuntu Linux. Basically Linux for learning purpose. And that's the reason I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) x86 on my [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) 11.

The problem is this: I am using a Cooler Master Devastator keyboard which has LED backlights, but in the guest OS (Ubuntu) the LED backlight is not working... Is there a solution to that? The scroll lock key toggles the LED backlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found on http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=296728
I had the same problem, and found a couple solutions, but this is the shortest command.

for the lazy:

xset led 3
(that turns it on)
xset -led 3
(that turns it off)